# Appcache and custom error pages

Tags: html, spring, html5-appcache

I've been working on an Spring MVC application that has custom error pages, these pages return a generic error message and the stack trace as an HTML comment. I'm currently developing the offline funcitonalities of this application using HTML5's Appcache. My manifest is something like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
... my explicit entries (not relevant) ...

FALLBACK:
... some fallback entries (not relevant) ...
<!-- This next line is relevant --!>
/ pageNotFoundOffline.html

SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

Which is supposed to serve a previously cached 404 page when the user can't connect to the server, the problem is that it also serves this 404 page when an error occurs, thus rendering completely useless the custom error page already implemented in the application.

Why i want to do this? i want that whenever a user tries to access any page on my application and the request fails with a 404 (either because the is no available internet connection or because the servers are down), that user is informed that the request failed and he or she is being redirected to our offline functionalities, also i want to inform the user when he or she succesfully reached our servers but an internal error occurred (through the custom error page).

Is there a workaroud for this problem?, what i would like to accomplish is the cached 404 page to be served only when there is a 404 exception and the custom error page returned by the server to be displayed when there was an internal error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not possible with appcache - the fallback intercepts all server errors. The [specification for appcache](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#changesToNetworkingModel) says: "If this results in a redirect to a resource with another origin (indicative of a captive portal), or a 4xx or 5xx status code or equivalent, or if there were network errors (but not if the user canceled the download), then instead get, from the cache, the resource of the fallback entry corresponding to the fallback namespace f. Abort these steps."

If you can use the more modern way of doing things, [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), I would recommend using that, as that will let you do what you want.